# Black or blank screen coming after visual studio code update

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using visual code and press update in the right side corner and after that Black or blank screen coming while i open the visual studio code.

I tried uninstall the version and install again but nothing work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by change the file  at this location C:\Users\username.vscode

At this location i found [image: argv]

I have updated the argv file and make it like this :

```
// This configuration file allows you to pass permanent command line arguments to VS Code.
// Only a subset of arguments is currently supported to reduce the likelyhood of breaking
// the installation.
//
// PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING THE IMPACT
//
// NOTE: Changing this file requires a restart of VS Code.
{
    // Use software rendering instead of hardware accelerated rendering.
    // This can help in cases where you see rendering issues in VS Code.
    // "disable-hardware-acceleration": true,

    // Enabled by default by VS Code to resolve color issues in the renderer
    // See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51791 for details
    "disable-color-correct-rendering": true,

    
}
```

this worked for me and after this i am able to use visual studio code.

Thanks